# Find total active user sessions / online users in Windows Azure with multiple instances scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, azure, cloud

Is there any way using which we can find the total number of active users in a ASP.NET MVC web application which is deployed on windows azure with multiple web role instances.

Application uses Azure ACS and there is no session involved i.e. it is not using any distributed cache to store sessions across role instances.

I am aware about in general how this is achieved i.e. using the application object variable where you initialize it in the App_Start and then increment or decrement in Session_Start / Session_End methods but this wont work in multiple instance scenarios as session is not distributed across the web role instances.

Comment: well, use the distributed cache to keep track of active users. Azure is not (much) different than *any* farm scenario in which you split the load into multiple servers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions asked here must demonstrate minimum understanding of the problem being sloved, along with demonstration of elementary Internet search skills - what user have already tried, why it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks astaykov for your comments, however I guess you misunderstood the question itself. what I am trying to do is to see and find a way (if there is any) to solve the mentioned problem without using the distributed cache.

Comment: You could store the last seen date of each user in the database and do a query.

Comment: Adding another point to this,
Keeping sessions in azure distributed cache wont help in finding actual active sessions, as when sessions are stored out-proc then Session_End doesn't trigger in ASP.NET